# Formaction attribute is not working when input text has required attribute

Tags: html

I have this code, I use formaction attribute to return in home.html
but it's not working because of required attribute.

```html
<form action="post">
Name:
<input type="text" name="name" required>
<br>
Email:
<input type="email" name="name" required>
<button name="Send" id="send">Send</button>
<button name="Return" id="return" formaction="home.html">Return</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `formaction` attribute working fine. I can use the Network tab in my browser's developer tools to observe that when I click `Return` (in the live demo in your question) the form is submitted to `home.html`.

The `required` fields are still required (so I have to fill them in before that happens), but that is to be expected.

---

It sounds like your goal is to provide an exception and not need the user to enter any data when submitting the form to `Return`.

That isn't possible without adding a bunch of JS but you're approaching the problem from the wrong angle in the first place.

It looks like you want something for the user to click on that will abort filling in the form and **just** go to a different URL. There's no data submission involved.

That isn't a job for a submit button.

Use a link instead.

```
<a href="home.html">Return</a>
```

You can apply CSS if you want it to *look* like a button, but I wouldn't recommend it. The visual appearance of the button implies that the form data will be sent somewhere, and that isn't what you are doing.

Comment: ok i understand, but if i need to use js theni need to disabled the required attribute?

Answer (score -1):

You should refer to homepage at the form tag

```
<form action="home.html" method="POST">
```

and for the submit

```
<input type="button" name="Return" id="return">
```

Comment: i don't want to use action in my <form></form> tags